# Why can't Idle import from .py files created after it was launched?

Tags: python

I can't explain this phenomena, other than to assume that Idle *somehow* works off of a `snapshot` of the filesystem, taken at launch-time.

Repro steps:

- create a `myLib.py` file with (e.g.):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

pre_launch_str = "Pre-launch!"
# post_launch_str = "Post-launch!"
```

- launch Idle (from the containing folder)
- `from myLib import pre_launch_str` works as expected: the string is imported/usable
- Keep Idle running/open
- [from another application/terminal] *modify* `myLib.py` to include a new object (e.g.) `post_launch_str`
- `from myLib import post_launch_str` will throw an error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'post_launch_str' from 'myLib' (/home/myUser/myLib.py)```

Anyone know what the cause of this is?

Linux (zsh) + Python 3.10 inthe example above, but I've noticed this long ago (~Python3.5 and on MacOS too)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `importlib.reload(myLib)` does allow you to grab up-to-date content from myLib.py, *but* only if you imported the whole module with `import myLib`.

Based on Silvio's answer, I did some playing around:

- when using `import X`, it *is possible* to use `reload(X)` (note the lack of quotes around `X`)
- when using `from X import Y`

  - `reload(Y.__module__)` will throw: `TypeError: reload() argument must be a module`
  - `reload(X)` will throw: `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

As Silvio noted, `class` and `function` objects have the `.__module__` attribute (while `str`, `list`, `dict` do not), but they return the name of the module, not the module itself.

### Here be dragons!

It gets really weird if you mix the two import-types...

```
>>> from myLib import st
>>> st
'Pre!'
# Modify the value of `st` in myLib.py
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(myLib)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myLib' is not defined
>>> import myLib
>>> myLib.st    # it reused the `myLib` from memory
'Pre!'
>>> st
'Pre!'
>>> reload(myLib)
<module 'myLib' from '/home/user/myLib.py'>
>>> st    # still the originally-imported string
'Pre!'
>>> myLib.st
'Post!'
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with IDLE. When you've already put a module into scope (regardless of *which* names you imported from it), Python will never reload that module. It assumes the module's code has not changed and will use the in-memory version.

If you're planning to modify the module live during development, you'll need to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to reload it. You need a reference to the module itself. If you imported the module name as `import myLib`, then `myLib` will do. Otherwise, take a class or function that you imported and get its `__module__` (so `pre_launch_str.__module__` in your example). Then take that and call [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) on it.

```
from importlib import reload

reload(pre_launch_str.__module__)
```

Comment: Makes sense - though it seems to clash with the assumptions created by `from X import Y`

Comment: Both `import` types do the same thing internally: load a module and then put some names into scope. If the module's already loaded, then it won't reload. That's what `importlib.reload` does.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like strings don't get a `.__module__` so `reload()` use probably requires either a class/function to be imported when using the `from X import Y`, or a full-module import `import myLib`